# Xcode 7 simulator location services wont update

Tags: xcode7, core-location, simulator

I updated to El Capitan and Xcode 7. I tried to change the default starting location by going to Product> Scheme> Edit Scheme, but the location doesn't change for simulator builds. It stays the same even if I change the location at runtime by using Debug> Simulate Location.

It only detects a location changes on an app first installs or after the second startUpdatingLocation Core Location Manager call for run time changes.

I have resorted to using the device to test location changes.

Is any one else having similar issues? I have tested several versions of my app and have concluded that something is wrong with the newest version of Xcode. I am not seeing any similar posts online.